# If $\gcd(g(x),P_A(x)) \neq 1$ then prove that $g(A)$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

we had this question at our exam today and my professor told me my proof is very wrong mathematically.

> Given $A \in M_{n \times n } (\mathbb C)$, and a polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb C[x]$, and that $\gcd(g(x),P_A(x)) \neq 1$. ($P_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of A. Prove that $g(A)$ is not invertible.

So I said that if their gcd is not one, that means they share a common devisor. From Cayley Hamilton we know that $P_A(A) = 0$, and since we are in $\mathbb C$, this element which is their GCD takes $A$ to zero. Thus, since this element is shared for both $P_A(x)$ and $g(x)$ then this element does exist in $G(x)$ and sends it to zero, giving that $G(A) = 0$, which is in matrices words the zero matrix, which is not invertible.

now my professor told me that is totally wrong, and I agree with him.
What is the proper solution?

Comment: If $gcd(g(x),P_A(x))\neq 1$, then $g$ and $P_A$ have at least one common root $\lambda\in\mathbb C$. This $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, as any root of $P_A$, so $A-\lambda I$ is not injective. Now, $\lambda$ is a root of $g$, so one can write $g(x)=(x-\lambda)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q$. Then $g(A)=q(A)(A-\lambda I)$, so $g(A)$ is not injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $g(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $g(A)$ and since $\gcd(g(x),P_A(x))\neq 1$ then there's an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ (root of $P_A$) which's a root of $g(x)$ and then $g(\lambda)=0$ is an eigenvalue of $g(A)$ hence $g(A)$ isn't invertible.

Comment: So at least a part of my proof is correct, I mean in the good direction, no? That I said that if their gcd is not one then there IS a common root that gives 0 when we put $A$ in it.

Comment: Yes you were in the good direction:)

Comment: I hope he gives me a few points. I'm on the edge here :/ he gave us a tough exam.